# Python: TypeError : fn() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, typeerror

I've looked at the other examples and I don't understand how my problem is the same, so please excuse my ignorance if they really are.

I've thrown some functions into a module and have imported them. Here's a generic of the code in the module:

```
def foo(c):
    print c
def bar(c):
    foo(c)
```

When I call `bar` from my main code I get the `TypeError: foo() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are your functions in a class?

Comment: _How_ do you call `bar`?

Comment: Are you doing this in an interactive interpreter? And did you just change your `foo()` function from 0 arguments to 1 argument?

Comment: 1 - not in a class... I'm not advanced enough to do that... these are just some helper functions that I've put into a module - call it helper.py - that I call from another module - call it mother.py.  So when I call helper.bar(c) from mother that's when I get the error, and the error points to the calling of foo(c) in line 4 of helper.py

Comment: OK, it must be something on the machine I was using last night... this morning it works on my work machine...

Answer (score 1):

Actually it tells you what is missing - the argument :-)

A call without arguments:

```
>>> def foo(c):
>>>     print c
>>> def bar(c):
>>>     foo(c)
>>> bar()
TypeError: bar() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

A call with an argument:

```
>>> def foo(c):
>>>     print c
>>> def bar(c):
>>>     foo(c)
>>> bar('foobar')
foobar
```

Comment: OK, maybe I wasn't clear enough.  It was late when I wrote the above.  The functions are in a module (call it fns.py) that I call from another module (call it mother.py).  When I call from bar from mother - fns.bar(c) that's when I get the error.

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. Does your `mother.py` import the functions with `from fns import *`?

Comment: I'll have to see what I did at home... everything is OK at work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did it work? If not, please post errors here. If yes, consider setting an accepted answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the python kernel usually fixes strange bugs like this one.

---

Thats why it worked when un restarted the machine.

[Image of Button to restart de kernel in JupyterLab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MR15.png)

In JupyterLab is pretty common for the kernel to get stuck.

---

I hope it solves someone's problems!